# How these 2 approximation equations are gained of euclild distances?

Tags: systems-of-equations, approximation

[image]

$$r\gg 0$$

$$r_{1}\approx r-\frac{d}{2}\cos(\theta)\tag{1}$$

$$r_{2}\approx r+\frac{d}{2}\cos(\theta)\tag{2}$$

How the above approximation equations are made?

Comment: Hint - Drop a perpendicular onto the extended line AB from P. Let's call the point of intersection of this perpendicular and the extended AB, M. Use Pythagoras Theorem separately on triangles PMO and PMB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop a perpendicular from $A$ to the line of length $r$.  Call the point of intersection $S$.  $OS = \frac{d}{2} \cos \theta$. The argument is that $AP$ and $SP$ are approximately equal in length, because $\phi = \angle AOS$ is very small.  (Do you see why that follows?)

Similarly for $O$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Use law of cosines and $d\ll r$

$r_1^2=r^2+(d/2)^2-dr\cos(\theta)$

$r_2^2=r^2+(d/2)^2+dr\cos(\theta)$

Divide by $r^2$ and get:
$(r_1/r)^2=1+(d/2r)^2-(d/r)\cos(\theta)$

Use $d\ll r$ and expand square root to first order
to get $r_1/r\approx 1-(d/2r)\cos(\theta)$ or $r_1\approx r-(d/2)\cos(\theta)$

Similarly  $r_2\approx r+(d/2)\cos(\theta)$